# Ignore mixer animations for a specific bone in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using @react-three/fiber and other three.js related libraries to load a mixamorig and apply animations to the model. I have successfully done so and I can run overlapping animations and the weights work as intended with walkcycles/run/jump/idle all blending properly.

However, now I want to control the head rotation manually so that it will rotate towards a specific point in the world.

I am able to rotate the head properly, but it snaps immediately to a position once the head-tracking is enabled, rather than having a smooth (i.e. interpolated) transition to it's desired rotation.

So, in order to smooth the rotation I wrote an slerp function as follows:

```
function slerpRotateObject(point1, point2, object, dt) {
  const startRotation = object.quaternion.clone();

  const direction = point2.clone().sub(point1);

  const DELAY_LERP_FACTOR = 1;
  const t = 1.0 - Math.pow(0.001, dt / DELAY_LERP_FACTOR);

  const rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().lookAt(direction, new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));

  const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix);
  const endRotation = startRotation.slerp(quaternion, t);
  object.quaternion.copy(endRotation);
}
```

Great! The slerp works if no animations are applied to the model, but as soon as the mixer begins applying animations, the head rotation begins "fighting" the slerp function to rotate the head as well, so the head doesn't fully track towards the point anymore.

I attempted to fix this issue by stopping all animations of the mixer from affecting just the head bone before calling `mixer.update(deltaTime)`, so that my slerp rotations would be the only function applied to the head bone's rotation during the frame to no avail.

Is there a way to ignore mixer animations for a specific bone in three.js? Or any other way to achieve my desired effect?

By the way, here's my `useFrame` update function for the model and the `rotateHeadTowardsMouse` function:

```
useFrame((_, deltaTime) => {
  mixer.update(deltaTime);
  rotateHeadTowardsMouse(mouse, deltaTime);
});

function rotateHeadTowardsMouse(beginHeadTracking, group, canvasRef, mouse, deltaTime) {
  if (beginHeadTracking) {
    const headBone = group?.current?.children?.[0]?.children?.[2]?.skeleton?.getBoneByName('mixamorig9Head');
    const headBonePosition = headBone?.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3());
    const headBoneVector3 = new THREE.Vector3(headBonePosition.x, canvasRef?.current?.clientHeight, headBonePosition.z);

    if (headBoneVector3) {
      slerpRotateObject(headBoneVector3, new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y - 250, 1500), headBone, deltaTime);
    }
  }
}
```